# icon to be displayed when checked on dynamically generated accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having a scenario where if the check box is checked, an icon has to be displayed on the particular child accordion which is generated dynamically.

The following is my js file :

```
$(document).on("click", ".checkboxclas", function (e) {


    if($(this).is(':checked'))
    {


        var labelAttr = $(this).closest("form").find('label').text();
        var quantity = $(this).closest("ul").find("i.qt").text();
        var price = $(this).closest("ul").find("div.price").text();
        var itemname =$(this).closest("ul").find("label").text();
        var image = $(this).closest('ul').find('img').attr('src');

        var id_attr_val = $(this).attr("id_attr");
        //alert(image);



        var buildcart = $('<div id="addtoordersdiv"></div>');
        buildcart.append('<div  data-role="collapsible"><div class="prd-items-detials"><ul><li class="head"><form><label class="testtt" for="checkbox-mini-0">' + itemname + '</label></form></li><li class="prd-items-qt"><div class="col"><span class="prd-sm-img"><img id="imagesd" type="img" height="40" width="40"  src="'+image+'"/><span></div><div class="col"><i class="minus" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'"></i><i class="qt qt_'+id_attr_val+'" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'">1</i><i class="plus" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'"></i></div><div class="col"></div><div style="display: none;" class="price" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'">'+price+'</div><div class="total total_'+id_attr_val+'" id_attr="'+id_attr_val+'">'+price+'</div></li></ul></div></div>');


        var dataa = '<div id="ordersdiv" style="display:none"></div>';


        $("#myordersdiv ul").append(dataa);
        $("#ordersdiv").prepend(buildcart);
        clcik++;
        $("#myordersdiv").find("i.myorderhead22").text(clcik);

        $("#myordersdiv").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#addtoordersdiv').remove();
        clcik--;
        $("#myordersdiv").find("i.myorderhead22").text(clcik);
    }

});

$(document).on("click", ".imgclss", function () 
{

createAccordian();
//var id_attr_val = $(this).attr("id_attr");    


})



$(document).on("click", ".minus", function () 
{

    // alert('sss');
    var ul = $(this).closest("ul");
    $(this).next().text(parseInt($(this).next().text()) - 1);
    var price = parseInt(ul.find("div.price").text());
    var quantity = parseInt(ul.find("i.qt").text());
    ul.find("div.total").text(price * quantity);

    var id_attr_val = $(this).attr("id_attr");
    $(".qt_"+id_attr_val).text(quantity);
    $(".total_"+id_attr_val).text(price * quantity);

});
```

This is the fiddle where accordion is generated and icon named "icon-added" is called.

http://jsfiddle.net/K63fQ/

Now my requirement is "if the check box is checked, the "icon-added" has to be displayed on the accordion else no". Please help me out.

Comment: Your fiddle is just jQuery UI pasted into the JS box...

Comment: yes. How can i pass the condition. If checked, display icon?